# How can I populate the key value pairs of a new dictionary from an existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below. The first value (outside brackets) is the key. The first value in the braces is the value. 
Next in the square brackets are the metadata about the values. 
So for the key `185589766` and the value `183701781` there are two entries in the dictionary for two separate book names- one for `'"Cloud Computing" How to use it for your business'` and another for `"Learn How to Be a Success in Network Marketing"`. The second entry in the metadata is a probability value and the third entry is the sign `(+,-)`

```
25255942 {52691892: [('Internet of Things (IOT) Device Management', 0.4444444444444444, 'neg')], 72359602: [('Internet of Things (IOT) Device Management', 1.0, 'neg'), ('Questions', 0.07692307692307693, 'neg')]}
185589766 {183701781: [('"Cloud Computing" How to use it for your business', 0.4, 'pos'), ('Learn How to Be a Success in Network Marketing', 0.16666666666666666, 'pos')], 183702935: [('"Cloud Computing" How to use it for your business', 0.4, 'pos'), ('Learn How to Be a Success in Network Marketing', 0.16666666666666666, 'pos')], 110069642: [('Learn How to Be a Success in Network Marketing', 0.3333333333333333, 'pos'), ('How to make money in network marketing', 1.0, 'pos')]}
110370832 {9420651: [('Dinner and a Movie', 0.5, 'neg'), ("Let's get a Furmeet setup and make a home here", 0.14285714285714285, 'neg'), ('Afterwork Happy Hours and Dinner', 0.5, 'neg')], 76185392: [('Dinner and a Movie', 0.5, 'neg'), ("Let's get a Furmeet setup and make a home here", 0.3333333333333333, 'neg')], 9779381: [("Let's get a Furmeet setup and make a home here", 0.25, 'neg')]}
```

Now I need to create a new dictionary from this existing dictionary. The new dictionary will contain keys, values, book names of the existing dictionary excluding the signs and the probability values. Apart from that it will store a **new** entry 'propagation probability' in the metadata. How can I do that?

The new entry 'propagation probability' should be added to the dictionary in the format below (added sample for a key):

```
25255942 {52691892: [('Internet of Things (IOT) Device Management', prop_prob1)], 72359602: [('Internet of Things (IOT) Device Management', prop_prob2), ('Questions', prop_prob3)]}
```

where prop_prob1, prop_prob2, prop_prob3 are the respective propagation probabilities. These propagation probabilities will be computed by using an algorithm and will be stored in the new dictionary.

Comment: That's not a valid python dictionary. Could you put the *actual* data in the question please?

Comment: Actually this data is retrieved from a pickle file. After loading the file I can see the data in that format only.

Comment: How do you want the propagation probability to be formatted in the meta data?

Comment: @Jako I added that information to the details of the question.

Comment: @Debbie In the format you gave you retained the sign value, is that a mistake?

Comment: @Jako yes. edited.

Comment: @Debbie Ok great, check out the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
new_dict = {}

for key in some_dict:
    new_dict[key] = {}
    for subkey in some_dict[key]:
       prop_prob = # Your calculation here
       new_entry = [((some_dict[key][subkey][i])[0], prop_prob) 
                    for i in range(len(some_dict[key][subkey]))]
       new_dict[key][subkey] = new_entry
```

Comment: It seems to be what I desired. Thank you very much.